# flink on yarn error "Yarn only has -1 virtual cores available"

Tags: apache-flink, cloudera

I have installed Cloudera CDH 6, and then I want to install flink using package from flink website, and run it "flink on yarn".

I have down the following steps: 
1. edit /etc/profile

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.0.0-1.cdh6.0.0.p0.537114/lib/hadoop/etc/hadoop

2. execute ./yarn-session.sh -n 4 -jm 2048 -tm 2048  -s 3 -nm FlinkOnYarnSession -d -st

But it always shows：

The number of virtual cores per node were configured with 4 but Yarn only has -1 virtual cores available. Please note that the number of virtual cores is set to the number of task slots by default unless configured in the Flink config with 'yarn.containers.vcores.'

This is a new cluster and there is no job running, and I see in yarn webUI there is 20 vcores available.

Please help with this problem. Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in flink, and the details can be viewed here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5542

With flink 1.6.1 version, I solved this by modify yarn-site.yml and add cpu-vcores parameter.

```
vim $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/yarn-site.yml
```

add yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores property, for example set it to 8.

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>8</value>
</property>
```